# Why disallow subclasses to override superclass properties with a derived type?

Tags: swift, oop, subclassing

Swift programming language allows subclasses to override superclass properties with the same type T, but not with a different type S, not even when S derives from T. Here is a quote from https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Inheritance.html:

> You must always state both the name and the type of the property you
>   are overriding, to enable the compiler to check that your override
>   matches a superclass property with the same name and type.

When overriding methods, Swift does allow an overriding subclass method to return a type that derives from the superclass method return type.

My question is: what is the motive for disallowing subclasses to override superclass properties with a type S that derives from T?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not actually limited to Swift. This would break polymorphism. See the subtyping rules on [wikipedia: Subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping)

Basically, consider the following example:

```
class A {
   var x: NSObject?
}

class B: A {
   override var x: NSNumber?
}
```

and consider:

```
let b = B(x: 1)
let a: A = b // it's a subclass, polymorphism allows to assign it to A
a.x = NSObject() // let's assign NSObject() because A.x takes NSObject
print(b.x) // b.x should be a NSNumber now but we have assigned a NSObject?
```

You have to realize that a property is a combination of two functions, a setter and a getter. You could add a more specific type (covariant type) to the getter (return value of a function) but you cannot do that for a setter (parameters of an overriden function require contravariance).

That also tells you that this would work with a readonly property:

```
class A {
    var x: NSObject? {
        return NSObject()
    }
}

class B: A {
    override var x: NSNumber? {
        return NSNumber()
    }
}
```